# Counting 2-factorizations

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Suppose I have a $2k$-regular graph. By Petersen's theorem this has a $2$-factorization. The questions are:

Is there some nice way to count $2$-factorizations, or is it a hard problem?

Are there any results on the statistics of the number of $2$-factorizations (over all $2k$-regular graphs)

Comment: For cubic graphs that's the same as counting 1-factors. I am pretty sure there is no general formula for this. It would be interesting to see whether there actually is a polynomial algorithm counting 1-factors in cubic graphs?